# Show that $\int_{0}^{1}x^{m}(1-x)^{n}dx=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}(1-x)^{m}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to show that:
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{m}(1-x)^{n}dx=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}(1-x)^{m}dx$$
For any positive integers $n$ and $m$. Which is true if I try to evaluate it numerically.

I tried to use the binomial theorem, but then I end up with:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}
\sum_{i=0}^{n}
\begin{bmatrix}
n \\ 
i
\end{bmatrix}x^{m+n-i}
dx
=
\int_{0}^{1}
\sum_{i=0}^{m}
\begin{bmatrix}
m \\ 
i
\end{bmatrix}x^{m+n-i}
dx
$$

There is a term $x^{m+n-i}$ on both sides which looks like there should be something I can do with it to simplify but then I am stuck.

This is an exercise following Apostol's Calculus I Chapter 5 where integration by substitution is discussed, but it is not clear how to use integration by substitution here.

Comment: You can use the substitution $t = 1-x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Make the change of variables $1-x=t$.

Comment: I have $t = 1-x$. Then $dx = -dt$, $(1-x)^{n}=t^{n}$ and $x^{m}=(1-t)^{m}$, so I get $$-\int_{0}^{1}(1-t)^{m}t^{n}dt=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}(1-x)^{m}dx$$but there is this minus sign, what do I do with it?

Comment: @Fazzolini You must also adjust the bounds of integration after the substitution; you should actually have $$- \int_1^0 ...$$

Comment: I forgot to change the bounds, thank you!

Comment: @Mhenni: (+1) Is this integral related to Beta function $B(m,n)$? Thanks.

Comment: Of course, @Babak : $$B(m+1,n+1):=\int_{0}^{1}x^{m}(1-x)^{n}dx$$ and what this question asks is to show the Beta function is symmetric: $\,B(m,n)=B(n,m)\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio: I see. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks for answering Babak S.

Comment: @T.Bongers: Thanks for answering the OP.